# Por que o Ajax está funcionando apenas na primeira vez?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho uma tabela com alguns valores armazenados nela. Nesta tabela também tenho dois botões onde eu posso esconder os valores, deixando apenas o nome da tabela e outro botão que faz o filtro das informações que quero.

Meu problema é que o botão filtro esta funcionando apenas uma vez, além de alterar o comportamento do outro botão de esconder a tabela.

Aqui o código que estou usando para manipula os botões:

**JS**

```
$('#mostraLancamento').hide();

...

$("#filtroTrabalho").click(function(){
        var idusuario = $(".filtro").attr("id");
        //alert(idusuario);
        $.post("filtro.php",

            {'param':idusuario}, 

                        function(j) {
                                $('.dados').remove(); 
                                $('.conteudoAjax').load('home.php');    

                        }, "json"); 

    });


...

$('#ocultaLancamento').click(function(){
        $('#panelLancamento').hide();
        $('#ocultaLancamento').hide();
        $('#mostraLancamento').show();
    });

    $('#mostraLancamento').click(function(){
        $('#panelLancamento').show();
        $('#ocultaLancamento').show();
        $('#mostraLancamento').hide();
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="ocultaLancamento">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-small" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="mostraLancamento">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="filtroTrabalho">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" aria-hidden="true">
       <?php 

          ...               

        ?>
       </span>
      </button>

...
```

**Console:**

```
 XHR finished loading: POST "http://servidor/painel/filtro.php". jquery-1.9.1.js:8526


 XHR finished loading: GET "http://servidor/painel/home.php". jquery-1.9.1.js:8526
```

Comment: Após chamar a primeira vez a opção de filtro, verifique o console do navegador e veja se não está apresentando nenhum erro, provavelmente na primeira vez que ele está executando está ocorrendo algum problema que está inviabilizando as próximas execuções, verifique isto e informe/edite a pergunta se houver algum erro sendo apresentado no console após a primeira execução.

Answer (score 4):

A maneira como você adiciona código ao evento dos controles (`$('#ocultaLancamento').click(function(){...`) fará com que esta associação seja perdida quando componente for recriado, e o componente é recriado se for re-renderizado devido a uma requisição Ajax.

Use o método **on** do [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/) para associar funções aos eventos dos controles. Por exemplo:

```
$('#ocultaLancamento').on('click', function(){
    $('#panelLancamento').hide();
    $('#ocultaLancamento').hide();
    $('#mostraLancamento').show();
});
```

Isso garante que a função seja associada novamente mesmo depois de o controle ser recriado.

Answer (score 1):

No seu trecho HTML não vi nenhuma DIV que possua a classe "conteudoAjax". Possivelmente você esteja tentando acessar uma div que não existe no seu código, uma vez que, quando você solicitou uma segunda vez o filtro, você por ventura tenha sumido com ele.

Faça o seguinte teste. Crie uma div com a classe e teste mais de uma vez o load:

```
<div class="conteudoAjax"></div>
```

Garanta que ela não será sobescrita por nenhum ajax e tente novamente.